# can't install rails in windows 7 - unexpected end of file error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm new at ruby. After installed the latest version of ruby, I started to install sqlite3 and rails but I failed to install rails, followed the guide, this is the command:

**gem install rails**

 and I got this error

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
>       unexpected end of file

Comment: Installing the `rails` gem by ignoring the dependencies won't help in your work with `rails` since it depends on many gems, and they need to be present. Here's the same error message in a different context, but on Windows: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems-mirror/issues/14 Perhaps best to put the full error trace in the question, and hope someone gives a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to install it just add --ignore-dependencies at the end.

> gem install rails --ignore-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times a `Zlib::GzipFile::Error` means RubyGems had issues parsing the response of the server.

This happens when your internet connection/configuration is behind a proxy that RubyGems is not aware of.

Please look at your internet options to determine the proxy configuration (it will look like `http://user:pass@proxyserver:8080/` or similar (user, pass, proxyserver and port are examples)

Once you have that information, you can tell RubyGems to use that:

```
gem install rails --http-proxy=http://user:pass@proxyserver:8080
```

Or you can set it as environment variable:

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@proxyserver:8080/
```

See `gem help install` for more details on the proxy documentation.